# Chrome notifications API img

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I'm trying to fire a chrome notification ( in a chrome extension ) with the following code:

```
 var opt = {
       type: "basic",
       title: "Deploy",
       message: "It worked!",
       iconUrl: "test.png"
    };
    chrome.notifications.create("", opt, function(id) {
       //console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    });
```

But it shows me the following message :

"Unchecked runtime.lastError while running notifications.create: Unable to successfully use the provided image. "

My image "test.png" is in the root folder of my app( with the manifest.json file ), but I've tried to put the picture also in other folder of my app, it never worked!

I've correctly added the permission for notifications, so I really don't know where the problem is ! 
Any ideas ?

Thank you,

EDIT: I found the solution ! The image needed to be 80*80 !